# PHP hyphens problem when using a variable

Tags: php, apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is a search engine.

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)\.html$ /results/news.php?name=$1
```

And my link structure is `/news/what-is-up.html` using hyphens.

When I search for **/results/news.php?name=hello world** I get different results than when I use **/news/hello-world.html**

It seems that the search is searching for `hello-world` using hypens instead of spaces, I could easily solve it using a `+` sign but I want to use hyphens. Does anyone know how to do it?

This is the code I use for converting the name variable into URL friendly:

```
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
if( !empty($replace) ) {
    $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
}

$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
$clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
$clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

return $clean;
}
```

and my search engine uses http location like this:

```
if ($q != '') {
   header( 'Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/news/'.toAscii($q).'.html' );
   die();
}
else
{
    header('Location:http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/news/');
    die();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code-block for replacing the hyphens? I don't think that it is a matter to your rewrite rule.
/results/news.php?name=hello-world should produce the same results than /news/hello-world.html

Comment: And the keyword is urldecode() but only working for '+' signs.

Comment: What if someone is actually looking for `hello-world` and not `hello world`?

Comment: im starting to think the problem is using redirect in the search... but i dont know how to do it differently :)

Comment: @Peibol: No, the problem is rather doing this needless “URL friendly” thing. It adulterates the user input so that the result might not be what the user intended.

Comment: and what about hyphenated words?

Comment: i do this for SEO purposes, but i think i have the wrong aproach here. I will need to tweak it somehow so all the possible variables (hyphens, quotes, and everything) are searchbale but in the URL they dont appear.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly use str_replace to replace a hyphen with a space before submitting it to your search.

```
$search_term = str_replace("-", " ", $incoming);
```

Comment: This fixed the problem temporarily, but it seems that i have another one now as stated in the above commentaries. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem might be that incoming vars via a get string will be urlencoded so hello world will appear as hello%20world, so you first have to urldecode() the var just in case the user has entered spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle word splitting on your end since it's being rewritten.

What you can do is have

> RewriteRule ^news/(.*).html$ /results/news.php?name=$1&**rewrite=true**

and if $_GET['rewrite'] is present, you do str_replace("-", " ", $incoming)